# Conversion of signed bit-vector expression to integer throws AccessViolationException

Tags: z3

I am using the Z3 .NET API and am trying to convert a signed bit-vector expression to integer using the following code:

```
using (Context context = new Context())
{
    Expr e = context.MkBV2Int(context.MkBV(-1, 32), true);
}
```

But, I get the following exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at Microsoft.Z3.Native.LIB.Z3_mk_bv2int(IntPtr a0, IntPtr a1, Int32 a2)
   at Microsoft.Z3.Native.Z3_mk_bv2int(IntPtr a0, IntPtr a1, Int32 a2) in Z3 src\src\api\dotnet\Native.cs:line 2386
   at Microsoft.Z3.Context.MkBV2Int(BitVecExpr t, Boolean signed) in Z3 src\src\api\dotnet\Context.cs:line 1800
```

But, conversion of unsigned bit vectors works great.

What is the problem? And how do I fix it? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting this problem! There was indeed a bug in the lower level C API. This has now been fixed in the unstable branch (see [here](https://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/9c052f589d7a535ea46837f1feff095e57cfc878)).